# UIImageView showing content with severe delay

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, storyboard, interface-builder, delay

This is really a mystery for me (iOS 8, Xcode 6.x, Storyboard):

I'm presenting one view controller (VC) modally, overlaying on the VC presenting it.

On the VC being presented, there's a static image with pdf assets. When the VC is loaded, the image doesn't show up, then after like 20 seconds, it shows up.

What could have gone wrong? I have image cache setup inside this VC's code, so I removed that, result the same. I also tried to switch the asset to a png image, still the same. I'm really confused now, any comments?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your not setting the image on the main thread.

Wrap this around your line of code where you set your image.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // set your image here
});
```

Comment: I did try this, eventually I have to set the initial image to be something else or empty, and this worked. However if initiall in IB the image is set to the same pdf, even this doesn't work. I guess it's still not the root cause yet... Thanks for the reply.